# How do I fix "jQuery is not defined" error?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-mix

I am compiling my JavaScript code using Laravel Mix.

This is my JS code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

I have also tried:

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

This used to work earlier, but suddenly today, in my front end code, It is saying:

> jQuery is not defined

jQuery version: 3.6.0

laravel-mix version: 6.0.6

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap.js...

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: The same code is able to define $ but not jQuery. This is really strange

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap.js define with try{}..catch{}

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
} catch (e) {}
```

Comment: This is also not working

Comment: The same code is able to define $ but not jQuery. This is really strange